# Como remover mas de una fila de un DataGridView, C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, datagridview

La situación es la siguiente, necesito que el usuario al seleccionar con el mouse más de una fila en el DataGridView pueda eliminarlas al presionar el botón eliminar, actualmente solo se hacerlo para una eliminar una fila.

[image: ejemplo]

```
static int seleccionFila;

    private void ButtonInformacion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Esto es solo un ejemplo, para cargar el datagridview.
        dataGridViewItem.Rows.Add("A001", "Impresora", "80.00");
        dataGridViewItem.Rows.Add("B003", "Abanico", "250.00");
        dataGridViewItem.Rows.Add("A045", "Lanta", "167.00");
        dataGridViewItem.Rows.Add("T010", "Lampara", "45.00");
        dataGridViewItem.Rows.Add("R071", "Mesa", "450.00");

    }

    private void dataGridViewItem_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        seleccionFila = e.RowIndex;
    }

    private void ButtonEliminar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (seleccionFila > 0)
            dataGridViewItem.Rows.RemoveAt(seleccionFila);
    }
```

Comment: Porque tenes una variable que guarda la seleccion, cuando la grilla tiene entre sus propiedades una que te dice que filas estan seleccionadas?

Comment: Desconosco de esa propiedad que menciona, la forma que describo arriba es la que conosco.

Comment: Y leiste la documentacion de la grilla? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/selected-cells-rows-and-columns-datagridview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como bien te indica gbianchi en su comentario "la grilla tiene entre sus propiedades una que te dice que filas estan seleccionadas", es decir la propiedad `SelectedRows` que devuelve la colección de filas seleccionadas por el usuario, más detalles puedes encontarlos [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows?view=net-5.0).
Por tanto no haria falta la variable `static int seleccionFila;` ni el procediemiento `dataGridViewItem_CellClick` para capturar la fila seleccionada. Bastaria con el código siguiente.

```
//Esta variable no es necesaria
//static int seleccionFila;
private void ButtonInformacion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Esto es solo un ejemplo, para cargar el datagridview.
   dataGridViewItem.Rows.Add("A001", "Impresora", "80.00");
   dataGridViewItem.Rows.Add("B003", "Abanico", "250.00");
   dataGridViewItem.Rows.Add("A045", "Lanta", "167.00");
   dataGridViewItem.Rows.Add("T010", "Lampara", "45.00");
   dataGridViewItem.Rows.Add("R071", "Mesa", "450.00");
 }
 //Este procedimiento no es necesario
 /*private void dataGridViewItem_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
  {
    seleccionFila = e.RowIndex;
  }
  */
  private void ButtonEliminar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     if (dataGridViewItem.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
     {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow Rw in dataGridViewItem.SelectedRows)
        {
           dataGridViewItem.Rows.Remove(Rw);
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Excelente gracias, esta si es una verdadera respuesta completa.

Comment: @Ariel Gracias por tu reconocimiento y ademas por marcar como aceptada y puntear la respuesta, estamos aqui para ayudar.

Answer (score 1):

Créate una tabla nueva donde guardaras las **ID** o **Codigo_Item** al ir seleccionando, para luego eliminarlo.

```
Class tablaNueva
{ public string ID {get; set;} }

//Usar la tabla
    var tablaNueva= new tablaNueva();

//Para agregar registro a la tabla
        tablaNueva.add(new tablaNueva{ID = seleccionFila });
```

(Opcional)
Agrega otro DataGridView y en este vas visualizando la tabla en el que al final utilizara para eliminar varios registro al presionar el boton eliminar.

Eliminar (boton):
Ya que tiene una tabla nueva con los ID a eliminar puedes usar un:

```
Where (var D in tablaNueva)
{
  dataGridViewItem.Rows.RemoveAt(D.ID);
}
```

Nota: Solo te doy la idea en base a lo que veo. Yo recomiendo el LINQ